# Minesweeper challenge #5

Tags: logical-deduction, probability, minesweeper

Coming back to another Minesweeper challenge...

I've run into another "unsolvable corner" (corner of a puzzle where there isn't enough information to be 100% certain that any particular square that isn't a mine).

Which squares in the below puzzle have the highest chance of being safe, and what are the chances I can fully solve the puzzle based on the clues present? There are 6 mines remaining.

[image: Puzzle]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your current situation, I believe that

> You should fill in the two bottom middle boxes as being flags, because they are 100% mines. Then, the top two squares remaining contain at most 1 flag. The chance of guessing a safe square is 50% (see diagram). The three squares in column two that are touching the 4 each have a 1 in 3 chance of being a mine (there is definitely 1 mine somewhere in those three), so the chance of guessing a safe square is 67% (and the chance of being a mine is 33%. The remaining five squares have 2 mines, so there is a 40% chance of guessing the mine and a 60% chance of guessing a safe square.

I would therefore guess that

> Take a guess at one of the three squares in column 2 that are touching the 4, that will give you the best odds.

Diagram:

> [image: Minesweeper]

Comment: Ah, my eyes somehow skipped the two ones in the bottom right...

Comment: How did it go?? @gparyani

Comment: @gparyani Doesn't the question also ask for the chance of fully solving the puzzle?

Comment: @noedne That answer is provided here.

Comment: @gparyani What is the answer? I only see the probability of the first square clicked being a mine.

Comment: @noedne assuming you still care, I have tried to answer the question a little better

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised nobody other than noedne thought that the other answer wasn't complete.  The question clearly wanted to know the odds of solving the minesweeper puzzle, a non-trivial question even at this size.

> There are 60 states the mines can have in this puzzle.  First thing to note is that the 50/50 pair at the top of the puzzle is always going to be a 50/50 shot.  No clue from the opposite side will shed any light on it.  Therefore it makes sense to guess there first because it is possible that we can learn something from it.  I choose to click the left cell but it doesn't matter which you pick.
>
>
> [image]
>
>
>  I'm not going over every decision I made, but there are a few places where guessing in the right spot might save you in the right scenario.  For example, my second guess was commonly the middle-right cell.  It has both better odds and better chances of being informative.  I highlighted in yellow a cell that I "clicked" as a guess, but I know this diagram isn't as informative as I might like.  If this question wasn't so old, I might have spent more time on the diagram.
>
>
>  Answer is: probability is **13/60** or **21.67%** of winning, assuming you use my strategy.  I'm fairly certain you can't do better, a formal proof would take too much time (I think).